# Обезумить или обезуметь ?

Tags: орфография

Обезумить или обезуметь?

Как же будет правильнее?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оба слова в языке есть. Обезумить - глагол переходный, обезумить - сделать кого-то сумасшедшим.  Обезуметь - непереходный. Сам обезумел. 
Сравните: белИть - белЕть. Поскольку в данной паре суффиксы ударные, по ним легко восстановить в памяти правило: суффикс И - в переходных глаголах. Подобные пары: обессилел (сам) - обессилил(кого-то), обезлесел -обезлесил. Как правило, это глаголы с приставкой -обез(с)

Answer (score 1):

Сначала он её обезумил, а потом обезумел сам:)))